# PostGIS raster value of a lat/lon point

Tags: postgis, raster, point

I have a tiff raster in my PostGIS 2.0 database. I want to get the value of the raster at a  specified lat/lon point.

I have:

- postgresql-9.1
- postgis-2.0-svn with raster support
- a raster imported into PostGIS its SRID is 3035

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can transform the lat/lon point to raster CRS on the fly using ST_Transform(). Combined, the query looks like this:

```
ST_Value(your_raster, ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326),3035))
```

Answer (score 5):

The function ST_value:

http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Value.html

returns a raster value given a point in either x,y or lat,lon.

Comment: it works, but in this page the examples forces you to input your query in EPSG:3035, and i want to query in lat lon points..

Answer (score 5):

While ST_Value works, you still need to spatially join to the point as well:

```
SELECT ST_Value(your_raster.rast, ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326),3035))
FROM your_raster
WHERE ST_Intersects(your_raster.rast, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat),4326),3035))
```

Or with a table:

```
SELECT ST_Value(your_raster.rast, ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(your_table.lon,your_table.lat),4326),3035))
FROM your_raster
JOIN your_table ON ST_Intersects(your_raster.rast, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(your_table.lon,your_table.lat),4326),3035))
```