# Getting pixel value of GDAL raster under OGR point without NumPy?

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, pixel

I am working on a computational model of the abundance of wild pollinators across a landscape.  The model itself is complete, and I am now struggling with a post-processing step.

I have my GDAL pollinator supply raster that looks something like this (lighter colors mean higher pollinator visitation to a pixel):

[image: Greyscale raster representing pollinator supply on a landscape]

And I have an OGR shapefile of points representing sample locations on the landscape:

[image]

I'm trying to run some analysis on the pixels under these points, but to do so, I need to be able to extract the value of a pixel under a point.

Is it possible to extract the value of a pixel under a point using only OGR and GDAL through Python?  I would prefer to avoid reading the entire raster into memory through `ReadAsArray()`, as my output rasters are very, very large (too large to fit into memory).

I noticed [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25535/get-a-pixel-value), which is similar, but requires a command-line call.

Comment: What about ReadAsArray() and only reading in the point?  So only read the single cell that you are interested in?  You would need to convert from the point coords to pixel space and extract the necessary cell.

Comment: Look at the code for gdalsrsinfo, it shows you how to use GDALInvertGeoTransform() and switch between geographic space and pixel space:

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/apps/gdalsrsinfo.cpp

Comment: If you don't mind using PostGIS, see [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14960/postgis-raster-value-of-a-lat-lon-point). It is extremely fast and is just 1 SQL line.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind if I come across this problem and have access to a PostGIS database!  I didn't for this particular problem, so the GDAL solution below did the trick.  Thanks, though!

Comment: @kyle I don't know if things have changed but it looks like it is [GDALInvGeoTransform](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html#ae5445db4eedd786131bfd88eddd8b64d) not *invert* and [this is an example](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/apps/gdallocationinfo.cpp).

Comment: Check the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52777153/convert-longitude-latitude-to-pixel-values-using-gdal - they seem much simpler and more robust than the ones here, particularly the rasterio/xarray option. That option uses numpy under the hood, but I think should handle things fairly memory efficiently.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use the [gdal.Dataset](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal.Dataset-class.html) or [gdal.Band](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal.Band-class.html) ReadRaster method.  See the [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html) and [OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_apitut.html) API tutorials and the example below. ReadRaster does not use/require numpy, the return value is raw binary data and needs to be unpacked using the standard python [struct](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module.

An example:

```py
from math import floor
from osgeo import gdal,ogr
import struct

src_filename = '/tmp/test.tif'
shp_filename = '/tmp/test.shp'

src_ds=gdal.Open(src_filename) 
gt_forward=src_ds.GetGeoTransform()
gt_reverse=gdal.InvGeoTransform(gt_forward)
rb=src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

ds=ogr.Open(shp_filename)
lyr=ds.GetLayer()
for feat in lyr:
    geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    mx,my=geom.GetX(), geom.GetY()  #coord in map units

    #Convert from map to pixel coordinates.
    px, py = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(gt_reverse, mx, my)
    px = floor(px) #x pixel
    py = floor(py) #y pixel

    structval=rb.ReadRaster(px,py,1,1,buf_type=gdal.GDT_UInt16) #Assumes 16 bit int aka 'short'
    intval = struct.unpack('h' , structval) #use the 'short' format code (2 bytes) not int (4 bytes)
    
    print intval[0] #intval is a tuple, length=1 as we only asked for 1 pixel value
```

Alternatively, since the reason you gave for not using `numpy` was to avoid reading the entire array in using `ReadAsArray()`, below is an example that *does* use `numpy` and does not read the entire raster into memory, it only reads the raster value at the given point. It uses the built-in [gdal.ApplyGeoTransform()](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#ApplyGeoTransform) function in order to deal with axes rotations.

```py
from math import floor
from osgeo import gdal,ogr

src_filename = '/tmp/test.tif'
shp_filename = '/tmp/test.shp'

src_ds=gdal.Open(src_filename) 
gt_forward=src_ds.GetGeoTransform()
gt_reverse=gdal.InvGeoTransform(gt_forward)
rb=src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

ds=ogr.Open(shp_filename)
lyr=ds.GetLayer()
for feat in lyr:
    geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    mx,my=geom.GetX(), geom.GetY()  #coord in map units

    #Convert from map to pixel coordinates.
    px, py = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(gt_reverse, mx, my)
    px = floor(px) #x pixel
    py = floor(py) #y pixel

    intval=rb.ReadAsArray(px,py,1,1)
    print intval[0] #intval is a numpy array, length=1 as we only asked for 1 pixel value
```

Comment: And how can you save as csv, table or other object? An object with the same length of coordinates objetct

Comment: Here's the question, Luke. Thanks! https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269603/extract-raster-values-from-point-using-gdal