# PostGIS - store 2D elevation data

Tags: postgis, raster

I am new to PostGIS. How can I store 2D elevation data? I have uniform raster and for every [x,y], height is set. I want to be able to use this in my queries (something like `SELECT height FROM data WHERE index = [10, 15]`). I also need to write this data from my C++ application (it is not earth elevation data, it is some "planet" surface, that will be modified) and data retrieval must be realtime to be used on website.

So far I have come up with 2 ideas:

1. Use geometry and store 3D data 2)
2. Create "2D table" with N columns and N rows (not PostGIS, but classic Postgre solution)

Any better ideas or ways how this should be solved?

My data are approx. 3000x1500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I have used Raster, that is supported by PostGIS directly (but with GDAL extension installed).

It has functions, that suits my needs - see http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_reference.html

I can select value at a certain position directly, also update this value very easy. All operations seems fast enough in read mode (in times of ms).

Answer (score 1):

How big is your dataset?
You could create a fishnet grid in postgis [See here](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiCreateFishnet)

Then you could interpolate your raster with your grid with various tools (gdal/qgis):
[see here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46893/how-do-i-get-the-pixel-value-of-a-gdal-raster-under-an-ogr-point-without-numpy)

Dont forget to index your grid to optimize speed.
Good luck

Comment: The resolution of my dataset is approx. 3000x1500

Comment: Then creating a vector grid is the best bet, I've done this in the past.

Comment: By vector grid you mean fishnet?

Comment: Yes, sorry. If it is a oneshot, i would recommend using Qgis. Both tools (fishnet, and pointsamplingtool) are available and easy to use

Comment: It is not oneshot. Data will be updated from C++ application several times a day.

Comment: I see. then you should create the fishnet/vector grid just once. And then extract the raster values to you cells (http://gis-lab.info/qa/extract-values-rasters-eng.html) maybe this can help.