# python - find lat lon in geotiff

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff

I'm a python newbie.

I have a Geotiff file. I need to find coordinates in the Geotiff to find the position of a thermometer within the geotiff (the thermometer has the coordinates -115.47083484975207, 35.75837483423 e.g.).

I have these geotiff information:

```
PROJCS["NAD83 / UTM zone 12N",
GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010002,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",-111],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","26912"]]
```

How do I transform the geotiff, so that I get coordinates in lat and lon? I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922532/obtain-latitude-and-longitude-from-a-geotiff-file)

But I don't quite know if this leads me to a solution. I just want to know how to find to position of the thermometer in the geotiff.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Are you trying to find the *pixel* coordinates (e.g., column 12, row 102) of the pixel in which your latitude, longitude coordinates fall? Or are you simply trying to convert UTM coordinates to latitude and longitude?

Comment: Seems I cannot comment on your comment @Arthur so I am posting this as an answer (sorry, I am new here). Yes, the first one. I am trying to find the pixel coordinates in the geotiff (column x, row y) in which the lat/lon of the thermometer fall.

Comment: Converting from map to pixel coordinates has been answered before: [How do I get the pixel value of a GDAL raster under an OGR point without NumPy?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46893/how-do-i-get-the-pixel-value-of-a-gdal-raster-under-an-ogr-point-without-numpy)