# Extracting multiple raster data to point shapefile in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, shapefile, modelbuilder

I used raster iterator tool in ArcGIS ModelBuilder read several raster files in IMG format and extract values of corresponding raster files to a point Shapefile using "Extract multiple values" tool in spatial analyst. However, names of the raster files are too long and in extracted Shapefile fields they do not make any scene.

How can I extract part of the raster files name and use it as corresponding field name in the shapefile once the data are extracted?

Comment: Bring them to mxd, rename and use http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187322/extracting-values-to-points-without-arcgis-spatial-analyst/187338#187338

Comment: Alternatively add field names on tool interface

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preserve the names of your rasters, consider saving your shapefile as a feature class in a geodatabase . See [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/file-geodatabase-size-and-name-limits.htm) for feature class field name limits.

Comment: Once feature is within the geodatabase it works. But it has a common name in the feature fields e.g. if the first raster name is "raster_1.img" then other feature fields are named as "raster_1_1", "raster_1_2", etc after extraction of respective raster values to point feature  rather than using the actual raster name in the iterator. I think issue now with related to the way iterator is set up. Is there way I can pass name of the raster files to "Extraction multiple rasters to point" tool