# Extract Values to Point "RASTERVALU" rename field

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.4, extract

Is it possible to rename the RASTERVALU field on the attributes table, perhaps somewhere in the code?  I need to loop thru this command for several raster files due to "Extract MultiValue to Point" tool being buggy on version 10.4.  I know it is possible to do this with the multivalue tool in the arcpy code.  Or is there another solution?  Maybe add a blank field ahead of time and copy raster data to that field.  I'm willing to try anything at this point.

Comment: Did you try Alter Field? 

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000198000000

Comment: I have run into this same problem before. My solution was to create a new field, copy the RASTERVALU field values over to it, and then delete the RASTERVALU field, all in between each "Extract MultiValue to Point". Curious to see if there is a better way.

Comment: @K.Credo Since my multivalue tool bugs out, I will have to loop thru this code for each file.  I wish they would fix these bugs.

Comment: If you have few (500?) points try http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187322/extracting-values-to-points-without-arcgis-spatial-analyst/187338#187338