# Alternatives to Add Surface Information and Extract Values from points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, line

I am trying to add elevation data to an attribute table and am unable to use Add Surface Information and Extract Values as I have neither the spatial analyst nor 3D analyst license.

Are there any other tools/methods than can help me to achieve my goal?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187322/extracting-values-to-points-without-arcgis-spatial-analyst/187338#187338

Comment: QGIS Point sampling tool plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Convert the DEM elevation Data to Point using *Raster to Point*
2. Use the tool *Near* if you have an advanced license.
3. Use a *Spatial Join* if you do not have an advanced license.

If your input is a line then use *[points along line](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/creating-new-points-along-a-line.htm)* before step 2.

The GME [plug-in](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/gmedownload.htm) will do this in ArcGIS Desktop as well.