# What is a viable alternative to ArcGIS Pro "Sample (Image Analyst)" tool?

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, image-analysis

What I have:

- 1-band raster of a geodsic viewshed
- Points within the larger extent of the raster layer

What I need to do:

- Determine, through analysis, what point features DO NOT intersect the raster.

What works (kind of):

- Using the ArcGIS Pro "Sample (Image Analyst)" tool would work - generating a table that indicates which points intersect the band and which do not.

Issue:

- The organization I am working for does not actually have the Image Analyst extension to run this tool.

What I want to achieve:

- Find a tool/script/workflow that will allow me to generate similar data to the Sample tool, without the increased expenditure. Ideally still using ArcGIS Pro.

I know this could be simplified by transitioning the data into QGIS, however, I would like to explore possible solutions within the ArcGIS Pro platform.

Comment: I would use geopandas and rasterio to accomplish this: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/gallery/geopandas_rasterio_sample.html

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187322/extracting-values-to-points-without-arcgis-spatial-analyst#187338