# Extract raster values from point using GDAL

Tags: raster, gdal, extract

I want to extract raster value from point shapefile geometry. Raster size is 45924 x 61671 and shapefile has 11.000.000 points. I'm using `extract` function from Raster package in R but is not very fast.

I'd like avoid non-terminal methods like ArcGIS or QGIS and prefer some terminal options like gdal_xx.py mode at prompt.

As a result I need an object with 11.000.000 length in any format (CSV, txt, shp, etc).

I need repeat this procedure over several similar rasters.

Here's a nice [example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46893/getting-pixel-value-of-gdal-raster-under-ogr-point-without-numpy#comment428498_46898) but I don't know how to get or manipulate the resulting object and I'm not sure about their efficiency.

Comment: Your example is missing the link.

Comment: There appears to be two questions here--one a duplicate and another a follow-up to a previous question: 1) how to manipulate the resulting object from a GDAL sample operation? and 2) How to sample rasters with OGR point? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @Luke Question reopened.

Comment: I'd dump XY point coordinates and use gdallocation to get the raster values based on the coordinates. If you put all of that in a for loop as a bash/shell script (or directly in the terminal) you can add as many files as you want.

Answer (score 5):

Working from your provided example (which is the standard way of doing this), you can collect all the info in a python list.

Let's say your point layer has a unique ID field (if it doesn't, create one, as it really should). For this example, let's call it "id_points". You complement the code in your link with:

```
li_values = list()
for feat in lyr:
    geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    feat_id = feat.GetField('id_points')
    mx, my = geom.GetX(), geom.GetY()

    px = int((mx - gt[0]) / gt[1])
    py = int((my - gt[3]) / gt[5])

    intval = rb.ReadAsArray(px, py, 1, 1)
    li_values.append([feat_id, intval[0]])
```

[Original code attribution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/46898/2856)

This gives you a list of feature IDs and their associated raster values. You can then save it in a CSV (for example):

```
import csv

with open(r'csv/file/path.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    wr.writerows(li_values)
```

This will give you an output in the form of a table, which you can then open anywhere you want.

Comment: Thks, Roberto. I have a little concern about the line  `li_values.append([feat_id, intval[0]])`. Its possible to create an empty object with length X before the loop starts and fill it in each iteration? I dont know if in each iteration the PC have to create an object bigger and bigger under this scheme. In R (sorry but Im not so good in Python), for example reesults faster "li_values[positionX] <- intval[0]" than "li_values <- c(li_values, intval[0)]" or "li_values <- append(li_values, intval[0)]" (c, append, rbind, cbind, etc). Thanks!

Comment: @gonzalez.ivan90 You can using numpy arrays instead of lists, but they perform the same. Python list appending has very little overhead, you can use it without fear. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247298/size-of-list-in-memory

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple solutions from other users I've come up with this:

```
from math import floor
from osgeo import gdal,ogr
import csv

src_filename = '/path of your tif file.tif'
shp_filename = '/path of your shape file.shp'

src_ds=gdal.Open(src_filename) 
gt_forward=src_ds.GetGeoTransform()
gt_reverse=gdal.InvGeoTransform(gt_forward)
rb=src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

ds=ogr.Open(shp_filename)
lyr=ds.GetLayer()
feat = lyr.GetFeature(1)

li_values = list()
for feat in lyr:
  geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
  feat_id = feat.GetField('id_points')
  mx, my = geom.GetX(), geom.GetY()

  px = int((mx - gt_forward[0]) / gt_forward[1])
  py = int((my - gt_forward[3]) / gt_forward[5])

  intval = rb.ReadAsArray(px, py, 1, 1)
  li_values.append([feat_id, intval[0]])

with open(r'/path.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    wr.writerows(li_values)
```

Comment: this doesn't work properly