# Extracting coordinates from multipoint geometries?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, ogr, osgeo

I found this guide to get pixel value of raster under point: [Getting pixel value of GDAL raster under OGR point without NumPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/46898/2856)

I've a problem here:

```
for feat in lyr:
    geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    mx,my=geom.GetX(), geom.GetY()  #coord in map units
```

If I print `geom`, I can see all the point's coordinates but if I print `mx` or `my` the result is `0` for every feat.

if I print geom:

```
MULTIPOINT (9.48556682927651 39.1368546561669)
MULTIPOINT (9.46173837787432 39.1298387934389)
MULTIPOINT (9.54058251881085 39.441437960101)
MULTIPOINT (9.08688113454087 39.5390542536278)
MULTIPOINT (9.00215692841357 39.0072908447031)
MULTIPOINT (9.17741005408364 39.2751570664614)
```

if i print `mx` or `my`:

```
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
```

I'm using Python 3 maybe this could be a problem

Answer (score 3):

You have multipoint data, not points.  You need to pull out the point geoms from the multipoints.

Assuming only a single point per multipoint (as per your example):

```
wkt = 'MULTIPOINT (9.48556682927651 39.1368546561669)'
multipoint = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt )
point = multipoint.GetGeometryRef(0) # <--- Get the point at index 0
print(point.GetX(), point.GetY())
```

If you don't want to assume only a single point, you can loop through the points in each multipoint:

```
wkt = 'MULTIPOINT (9.48556682927651 39.1368546561669, 9.46173837787432 39.1298387934389)'
multipoint = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)
for i in range(multipoint.GetGeometryCount()):
    point = multipoint.GetGeometryRef(i) # <--- Get the geom at index i
    print(point.GetX(), point.GetY())
```

So when you're looping through the layer, do something like this:

```
for feat in lyr:
    multipoint = feat.GetGeometryRef()

    point = multipoint.GetGeometryRef(0) # <--- Get the point at index 0
    mx,my = point.GetX(), point.GetY()

    ## OR ##

    for i in range(multipoint.GetGeometryCount()):
        point = multipoint.GetGeometryRef(i) # <--- Get the geom at index i
        mx,my = point.GetX(), point.GetY()
```

Answer (score -1):

I write this and split the string

```
geom=feat.GetGeometryRef()
point=geom.Centroid().ExportToWkt() 
mx=float(point.split(' ')[1][1:len(point.split(' ')[1])])
my=float(point.split(' ')[2][0:len(point.split(' ')[2])-1])
```

Maybe someone will have this problem too