# Extract pixel value from shp with GDAL python

Tags: python, gdal

I have this code from here:

[Getting pixel value of GDAL raster under OGR point without NumPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46893/getting-pixel-value-of-gdal-raster-under-ogr-point-without-numpy)

```
from math import floor
from osgeo import gdal,ogr

src_filename = '/tmp/test.tif'
shp_filename = '/tmp/test.shp'

src_ds=gdal.Open(src_filename) 
gt_forward=src_ds.GetGeoTransform()
gt_reverse=gdal.InvGeoTransform(gt_forward)
rb=src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

ds=ogr.Open(shp_filename)
lyr=ds.GetLayer()
for feat in lyr:
        geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
        mx,my=geom.GetX(), geom.GetY()  #coord in map units

#Convert from map to pixel coordinates.
        px, py = gdal.ApplyGeoTransform(gt_reverse, mx, my)
        px = floor(px) #x pixel
        py = floor(py) #y pixel
        intval=rb.ReadAsArray(px,py,1,1)
        print intval[0] #intval is a numpy array, length=1 as we only asked for 1 pixel value
```

I have a .vrt that has 7 bands. I want to iterate over each band and to extract the pixel values for each band and to save it to a nested list.

```
   pixel_values=[['fid_1',value1,value2,value3,value4,value6,value7],['fid_2', value1,value2,value3,value4,value6,value7].. ..]
```

After that I want to export it to a csv.

Example:

```
pixel_values =[]
for band in range(1,8):
    pixel_value.append(intval[0])

pixel_value.to_csv('data.csv')
```

How can I extract the pixel value based on a point .shp file from a raster with multiple bands?

Comment: So what's your question? GIS SE is a *problem-solving* site. If your problem statement doesn't contain a problem, just a list of tasks which may or may not be addressed by the provided code (which uses a non-standard indent scheme), then it's difficult to anwser.

Comment: Please do not keep re-posting closed questions.  Fix your original one.

Comment: Please merge your two accounts and do not use them to ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not definitely want to write your own code, I would recommend to use the GDAL utility "gdallocationinfo" https://gdal.org/programs/gdallocationinfo.html.

> This utility is intended to provide a variety of information about a
> pixel. Currently it reports:
>
> The location of the pixel in pixel/line space.
>
> The result of a LocationInfo metadata query against the datasource.
> This is implement for VRT files which will report the file(s) used to
> satisfy requests for that pixel, and by the MBTiles driver
>
> The raster pixel value of that pixel for all or a subset of the bands.
>
> The unscaled pixel value if a Scale and/or Offset apply to the band.
>
> The pixel selected is requested by x/y coordinate on the command line,
> or read from stdin. More than one coordinate pair can be supplied when
> reading coordinates from stdin. By default pixel/line coordinates are
> expected. However with use of the -geoloc, -wgs84, or -l_srs switches
> it is possible to specify the location in other coordinate systems.
>
> The default report is in a human readable text format. It is possible
> to instead request xml output with the -xml switch.
>
> For scripting purposes, the -valonly and -lifonly switches are
> provided to restrict output to the actual pixel values, or the
> LocationInfo files identified for the pixel.

Comment: I'm new to programming and still I don't know to write my own code. Thank you for your answer but a code answer would help me a lot.

Comment: Gdallocationinfo is C++, but maybe the source code can still be useful https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/apps/gdallocationinfo.cpp. And actually there is also a Python version https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/samples/gdallocationinfo.py.